# Python Script Runs in Anaconda but there is a OSError

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

I'm trying to run a python script. when I try to then run the same program from Windows Powershell, I always get this error:

```
    File "D:\software\python3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 468, in <module>
        from ._rvs_sampling import rvs_ratio_uniforms, NumericalInverseHermite  # noqa
      File "D:\software\python3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_rvs_sampling.py", line 3, in <module>
        from ._unuran import unuran_wrapper
      File "unuran_wrapper.pyx", line 221, in init scipy.stats._unuran.unuran_wrapper
      File "unuran_wrapper.pyx", line 200, in scipy.stats._unuran.unuran_wrapper._setup_unuran
      File "messagestream.pyx", line 36, in scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream.__cinit__
    OSError: Failed to open file b'C:\\Users\\\xe7\xbd\x97\xe5\x8f\xaf\xe8\xb1\xaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scipy-qm7k_i7q'
```

This is my shell commond:
python detect.py --source data/images/bus.jpg --weights pretrained/yolov5s.pt

Comment: Seems, that your temp folder path is not correct, modify it with following link. [https://blog.csdn.net/datao3022/article/details/109186403]

Comment: thx for ur apply, i try to modify the temp foder, and it is working.